# Integrating a multivariable scalar potential

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Say I have a scalar function $V(x,y,z) :\mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R}$ which is a scalar potential of some vector field $\vec{F}$. I can write:

$\nabla V=\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\hat{x}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\hat{y}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\hat{z}$

I also know $\vec{F}=\nabla V$, so:

$\vec{F}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\hat{x}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\hat{y}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\hat{z}$

Now, if V was only dependent upon one variable, say $x$, could I  write the following connection ?

$V=\int \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dx}$

If so, what algebraic steps have I done here? It sure makes sense, but I fail at explaining it to myself. 
And what if V wasn't only a function of x, but of y and z too? Would it haven been right to write:

$V_x=\int \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dx}$

$V_y=\int \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dy}$

$V_z=\int \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dz}$

and then $V=V_x+V_y+V_z$ ?

Comment: No because $dx, \cdots$ are not vectors. You *can* say that $$V(\vec{r}) = \int_{\vec{r_0}}^{\vec{r}} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} + V(\vec{r_0})$$

Comment: I meant dx in the x direction, so I put a vector upon it.

Comment: Ok, then those follow from what I wrote.

Comment: Your comment didn't help me, I will be glad for elaboration.

Comment: This is just the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(x) = \int_a^x f'(t)\:dt + f(a)$ except it's a line integral from the fundamental theorem of line integrals.

Comment: I'm aware of that, yet from your comment it seems like what I've written is correct, and you have just written it in a compact form (dr includes dx,dy,dz) and I separated the integral to 3, one for each direction. Am I right?

Comment: The problem is that you assume in each step $V$ is only a function of one variable. It can't simultaneously be a function of one variable of three different variables. Ultimately your last statement is wrong and can only be written correctly in something similar to what I wrote. If $V$ really is only a function of one variable then the statements before the final one are correct.